# How to count the number of pairs and find the unpaired one?

Tags: algorithm, bash, shell, pattern-matching

I have a question about the text processing but without robust idea.

There's a log file which contains all the program execution info, like:

```
12:34:21 End   ./calc
12:34:25 Start ./gemm
12:34:26 Start ./gemm
12:34:27 Start ./jacobi
12:34:46 End   ./gemm
12:34:51 Start ./fab
12:35:02 End   ./jacobi
```

So in this case, I am trying to find the pair "Start" and "End" for specific program. For example, *jacobi* gets paired since it has Start and End. *fab* doesn't get paired because we cannot find its End info. *gemm* has two Start and one End. So, one of Start gets paired. I can set a rule, say, First Execution First Finish, then the second line *gemm* is not paired. *calc* is not paired since it has no Start info.

Using bash, I can grep Start or End, then sort the results and compare. Really don't think it's a robust solution. Any ideas?

Providing the bash code is good, the algorithm is also welcome!

Expected output:

```
12:34:21 End   ./calc     (unpaired)
12:34:25 Start ./gemm     (paired)
12:34:26 Start ./gemm     (unpaired)
12:34:27 Start ./jacobi   (paired)
12:34:46 End   ./gemm     (paired)
12:34:51 Start ./fab      (unpaired)
12:35:02 End   ./jacobi   (paired)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in bash v4 using associative arrays in exactly the same way as the following little awk program works, but the awk program is a bit easier and doesn't depend on your having a new bash version.

It basically sets up a queue for each value of the third field. The line number of the `Start` entry is added to the end of the queue. When an `End` is encountered, a `Start` entry is shifted off of the front of the queue if possible, and both entries are marked as matched.

```
awk '
  { line[NR] = $0; s = start[$3] }
  $2=="End" && s {
      matched[s] = 1; matched[NR] = 1; start[$3] = link[s]
  }
  $2=="Start" {
      if (s) link[end[$3]] = NR; else start[$3] = NR;             
      end[$3] = NR;
  }    
  END {
      for (i = 1; i <= NR; ++i)
          printf "%s (%spaired)\n", line[i], matched[i] ? "" : "un"
  }'
```

Comment: Thanks... what does `s = start[$3]` mean?

Comment: @brianyang: Set `s` to the value in the array `start` whose key is the third field of the current input line. Awk arrays are all associative arrays with string keys; undefined values are the empty string, which is false in a boolean context.